# grid search cross-validation on SVC probability output in sci-kit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to run a grid search cross-validation on the probability outputs of the `SVC` classifier.  In particular I'd like to minimize the negative log likelihood.  From the documentation it seems that `GridSearchCV` calls the `predict()` method of the estimator it is passed and the `predict()` method of `SVC` returns class predictions not probabilities (`predict_proba()` returns class probabilities).

1) Do I need to subclass `SVC` and give it a `predict()` method that returns probabilities rather than classes to accomplish my log likelihood cross validation?  I guess I then need to write my own `score_func` or `loss_func`?

2) Is cross-validating on this negative log likelihood dumb?  I'm doing it b/c the dataset is: a) imbalanced 5:1 and b) not at all separable i.e. even the "worst" observations have a > 50% chance of being in the "good" class.  (Will probably also post this 2nd question on stats q&a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you would, on both accounts.

   ```
   class ProbSVC(SVC):
       def predict(self, X):
           return super(ProbSVC, self).predict_proba(X)
   ```
2. I'm not sure if this would work since the majority class may still dominate the log-likelihood scores and the final estimator might still produce >.5 positive for samples of the minority class. I'm not sure, though, so please post this to stats.

Comment: 1) Thanks, 2) It is fine if the final estimator still produces > 0.5 for samples of the minority class.  In fact I'm pretty sure it will, I just want those probabilities to be as "good" as possible.

Comment: Seems like it needs to be `super(ProbSVC, self)` (i.e. params in the opposite order), but I'm quite new to Python so would prefer if someone confirms this

Comment: What would be the proper way to override the `SVC` constructor, set `probability=True` and pass all other arguments through to the `SVC` constructor.  Would it be something like:

    `def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProbSVC, self).__init__(probability=True, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

With the new scorer interface in the development version of sklearn, you do not need subclassing. You only need to define a scoring object as described [in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#score-func-objects)
Basically you need to do

`log_loss_score = Scorer(neg_log_loss, needs_threshold=True)`

This will possibly fallback to "decision_function", though.

You could also define a new scorer class that calls `predict_proba` on the estimator to ensure that it gets normalized probabilities.

Also, a pull request for log-loss would be welcome :)

Comment: We have a pull request for log-loss standing: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/1125. I've been wanting to merge that but didn't get round to it.